# Makefile to depend on third-party libs with cmake

Tags: cmake, makefile

all.

My main program uses third-party library A.
The main program uses autoconf and
the library A uses cmakefile to build.
Since converting one framework to another is pain to me,
I want to keep two different build mechanism.

Since the `main` depends on `libA`, I made `main` to depend on `libA` and
`libA` as force-build target.

When I change a source file of `main` and do `make` on `main`,
`libA` gets `cmake` and keep intact since nothing on `libA` is changed,
then only `main` gets build.

When I change a source file in `libA` and do `make` on `main`,
`libA` gets build forcefuly. But `main`'s dependency to `libA` is computed
before building new `libA`, linking does not get done.
Now I do make twice each time to get main safely.

How can I improve this build?
To summarize:

- `main` depends on `libA` (A)
- When I do `make` after changing source file of `libA`, I want to build `libA` first and build `main` (B)
- When I do `make` after changing source file of `main`, I want to build only `main` with original libA (C)
- When I do `make` without doing anything, I want to build nothing. (D)

With current setup, I cannot get (B).

Any helps will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about good old shell script (or bat file, if you happen to be on Windows)? Run cmake for libA, run make for main, profit!

You can use make as your batch engine, e.g.

```
all:
        Cmake libA
        $(MAKE) -f main.mk main
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. However other co-workers are expecting just `make` will do build. So I want to do in Makefile

Comment: You definitely can use make as your batch language, see update